# Jquery mobile tabs not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, tabs

I have a dynamic list which goes to a new page and one out of two tabs are active without being pressed (this is what I'm trying to do.) but when I go back to the dynamic list and select any other list it goes to a new page but none of the tabs are activate both appears plain.

**Here is my code (function) for dynamic new pages**

```
function goToMatchDetailPage(matchHome, matchAway){
    first_part_id = matchHome.substring(0,2);
    sec_part_id = matchAway.substring(0,2);
    var id = first_part_id.concat(sec_part_id);
    //create the html template
    var matchPage = $("<div data-role='page' id='index' data-url=dummyUrl><div data-role='header'><a data-rel='back' data-direction='reverse' href='#mainPage'>Back</a><h1>"
      + matchHome + "</h1></div><div data-role='content'><div data-role='tabs'>"
  + "<div data-role='navbar'>"
  +  "<ul>"
  +    "<li><a href='#fragment-1' id='tabId1'>" + matchHome + "</a></li>"
  +   "<li><a href='#fragment-2' id='tabId2'>" + matchAway + "</a></li>"
  +  "</ul>"
  + "</div>"
  + "<div id='fragment-1'>"
  +  "<p>This is the content of the tab 'One', with the id fragment-1.</p>"
  + "</div>"
  + "<div id='fragment-2'>"
  +  "<p>This is the content of the tab 'Two', with the id fragment-2.</p>"
  + "</div></div></div>");


    //append the new page to the page contanier
    matchPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);


    //go to the newly created page
    $.mobile.changePage(matchPage);

 }


 $(document).on('pageinit', function() {

     $(this).parents("div [data-role=tabs]").tabs( "option", "active", 0 );    

       $('#tabId2').addClass('ui-btn-up-b').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
       $('#tabId1').addClass('ui-btn-active'); 

    });
```

**Here I try to re-activate the a tab when a new page is created**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {

     $.mobile.activePage.find("div [data-role=tabs]").tabs( "option", "active", 0 );    

       $('#tabId2').addClass('ui-btn-up-b').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
       $('#tabId1').addClass('ui-btn-active'); 

    });
```

It appears with no tabs active

[image: This is what I don't want]

Comment: Why are you using .parents() on pageinit? The tab is a child of the page, so try $(this).find("div [data-role=tabs]").tabs( "option", "active", 0 );

Comment: It's giving me the same result, works great the first time I go to a new page but when I try again it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, pageinit is only called once, you can put it in pageshow which runs everytime the page is shown.  Also, instead of $(this) you could use $.mobile.activePage

Comment: I have update my code as you see in the edit. But still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the easy way. Just trigger a click on the tab button:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {    
   $('#tabId1').click();     
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/DZfBC/2/)**

To make it even more generic, find the first tab button on the page instead of using an ID:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {    
    $.mobile.activePage.find("div [data-role=tabs] ul li:first-child a").click();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/DZfBC/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer works great but once one problem is solve another problem is cause. Jquery is becoming a quite complicated language to learn. I know html, css, php and js but Jquery I still trying to get the hang of. How do you get so good you answered my previous question about swipe

Comment: I am not so good, I just keep playing around with it and discover as I go... You will get the hang of it with practice like anything else you want to learn.

Comment: lol, I check out your profile and you answered a lot, is there a way to contact you or you can contact me about my jquery swipe you ansered. Kind of the same thing is happening with the swipe functions now on new pages.

Comment: it is probably best to post a new question as others might also have better input.